# In typescript Can I map a type to have ? on property when its corresponding value satisfies a certain condition?

Tags: typescript

For example, given an object:

```
const TypeDef1 = {
    foo: {optional: true, type: 'string'},
    bar: {type: 'number'}
}
```

which conforms to type, say

```
type TypeDef = {
    [key: string]: {
        optional?: boolean,
        type: 'number' | 'string' | 'boolean'
    }
}
```

I want to have some reusable typing `Transform<T extends TypeDef>` such that

```
Transform<typeof TypeDef1>
```

gives:

```
{
    foo?: string
    bar: number
}
```

Is this at all possible in Typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of mapped and conditional types to transform the type definition to an actual type (provided we also use an `as const` assertion on the definition to make sure we preserve all type info.

```
type TypeDef =  { [key: string]: { optional?: boolean, type: 'number' | 'string' | 'boolean' } };
type TypeNameToType = {
    number: number,
    string: string,
    boolean: boolean
}
type TypeDefToType<T extends TypeDef> = {
    // The optional properties
    -readonly [P in keyof T as T[P]['optional'] extends true ? P: never]?: TypeNameToType[T[P]['type']]
} & {
    // The mandatory properties
    -readonly [P in keyof T as T[P]['optional'] extends true ? never: P]: TypeNameToType[T[P]['type']]
}

const TypeDef1 = {
    foo: {optional: true, type: 'string'},
    bar: {type: 'number'}
} as const


type X = TypeDefToType<typeof TypeDef1>
//   ^?
// type X = {
//     foo?: string | undefined;
// } & {
//     bar: number;
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEBEIDMoF4pQN5QNoGsIQAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBdUnAezGGtdoEMAbAPykARq1Z8IPWgBoooSKQDktAK4BbYREqKoAHyiKKNBjv2LR4ybR0BfKDYDcAKHnQ4kAHI81EGK3fQGFhOmJiqGlqk4ZqU0iGhRnT0pIkMcaFQFhJSImLZtE42LvCw8EjIfgEAPDBQEAAewBC0ACZkpZDlAHzo2PGYAPQDsAAW0Oyc3PxQYJTsWpwQZP1QALSUki3cfCB4AApQdFCEIKyotTztMLh7jLiKE1y8fIqMdY3NbXKUKtACUHsohAAG5aRhCDoQLw+SrwXDXW73VyvRiFKAAMj6GSGo2gaikLR4wFYlF2s3mlEWywy602212N0OtGORDOsCgl1gNzuDw4T34r3eTVa7Sovyg-1oIMiAOYkOhvn8cIRPORjFRRScAGNuBRIeUAIy9YIZZBiFiPKZ8UhiiCyVxKVL0RQ2dKhYQ8SgsB0GaJaF1ozk62gUJxh1xQAAavQC5VhkCqrjZsZQBq6ThxmAAegIM8MI9GgnmMlAzawIU69FAVK0UHQIC1nDi7Jjgpn3Z6ouoYk3hjYgA)

Comment: Fantastic! The things missing on my part is the "as const" you suffixed on TypeDef1 and the "keyof T as T[P]['optional'] extends true" which conditions on the key

Comment: my first error being I wrote this instead:
const TypeDef1: Params = {
     foo: {optional: true, type: 'string'},
     bar: {type: 'number'}
}
Could you explain further why it's necessary to remove the type qualifier and append a "as const"?

Comment: @Iceberglet you need to preserve in the type system as much information. the `as const` ensures that the type is more narrow. Hover over the type and see the actual type inferred. If you use  an explicit type annotation such as `TypeDef1: Params`, you don't really know anything more about what was assigned, you don't know the properties, or the optionality.. you just have the original  type